# Add a default bcc email in send email page?

Tags: email

In the send email page by clicking the send an email button in the activity section of a custom object, the user can manually put the bcc address. But our requirement is to add a default one for our company's support team.

Is that supported by Salesforce and how can we achieve it?

Comment: Do you want to force BCC for all emails? Or just default it?

Comment: @sfdcfox I think it should be force bcc for all emails. But default will also be working for us.

Answer (score 2):

There are no global or organization wide settings available to add default BCC for all emails.

Individual users need to setup through

> Setup ->Email->My Email Settings

You need to educate users to do this.

[image: bcc email]

Comment: Thank you for the information. Does that mean we should ask all our end users to set our company's support email as their return email address?

Comment: Yes, as there are no other ways we can do that. Exactly same thing we have done for our project

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *force* all users to always BCC a specific address, you can use the [Compliance BCC Email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_compliancebcc.htm&type=0) feature. To do so:

> - From Setup, enter `Compliance BCC Email` in the `Quick Find` box, then select **Compliance BCC Email**.
> - Select the `Enable` checkbox.
> - Enter your compliance email address.
> - Click **Save**.

Please note that:

> The BCC email is automatically sent to the address you specify for any
>   emails your users send, excluding system emails such as password reset
>   or import completion notifications.

In other words, system messages won't be BCC'd, but all emails manually sent will be forced to BCC the compliance address you specify, with no option to bypass this.